# I am missing wlp-kernel 2019.3.0.0

Tags: websphere-liberty

It used to be wlp-kernel package every time a new open liberty is released. Is it discontinued? Its size was almost 1/10 of the full profile.

Comment: where are you expecting to find this package? I assume Maven Central? If so, I see it here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.runtime/wlp-kernel/19.0.0.3

Comment: 2019.3.0.0 is a WebSphere Liberty beta version which was never in maven central and also isn’t an Open Liberty thing so I’m unsure what to suggest.

Comment: It was one of the downloadable packages in the IBM download page prior to 2019.3.0.0 version. I have found it in maven central. Thanks.